# jQuery Click function triggers SWFObject On Different DIV ... But Only In Firefox

Tags: jquery, flash, firefox, swfobject

Perhaps this is user error but I can't figure it out. It works -fine- in IE or Chrome, but fails in latest Firefox.

On this page:

http://detroittheopera.com/plot-view-unformat2

Click any Lyrics link and a jQuery click function shows/hides the next div. Fine.

Now click any triangle (a link which also has a jQuery function to loadSWF the SWF). Works fine also.

Now go back and click any Lyrics link. And it continues to work, BUT the SWF on the div above div will start playing.

I am pretty sure that the selectors do not overlap. I've tried to trace this in console but whenever it happens is deep inside the jQuery lib and I can't follow it.

What could be going on?

TIA,

---JC